# Include paths not working when building with devenv

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, project, devenv

I have a project created in Visual Studio
The Project has some header files included from another directory
To make it work in different machines I have an environment variable set to point the resource and then use it in my includes.
It works fine when I add the path as a environment variable for the user, using the Edit Environment variable option.
but If I use set cmd and set the variable and build the solution using devenv it doesn't recognize those paths

What could be the issue?
It is VS2013 project